# Misalignment of asp.net button within a table

Tags: javascript, html, css, asp.net

```
<table>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <asp:Label Text="Team :" runat="server"></asp:Label></td>
            <td>
                <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlProject" OnSelectedIndexChanged="itemSelected" AutoPostBack="True" runat="server"></asp:DropDownList></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <asp:Label Text="Project :" runat="server"></asp:Label></td>
            <td>
                <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlDetails" runat="server"></asp:DropDownList></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <asp:Button ID="btnBugSubmit" Text="Bug" OnClick="btnBugSubmit_Click" runat="server"/></td>
            <td>
                <asp:Button ID="btnIssueSubmit" Text="Issue" OnClick="btnIssueSubmit_Click" runat="server"/></td>
            <td >
                <asp:Button ID="btnReqSubmit" Text="Requisition" OnClick="btnReqSubmit_Click" runat="server"/></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

One of the buttons "btnReqsubmit" (circled below) is not aligned and I don't know why.
Is there anything wrong in my code ?

[image]

Comment: Can you please create jsfiddle.net demo with _complete_ and _relevant_ code

Comment: One possible fast trick to solve this; remove all three td's from your last tr and have one td with colspan=3 specified,  and have all your buttons in it....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Possible solution. Ideally there should be same number of `td` in every row.
 In your first `tr` you have only 2 `td` and in others you have 3 `td`.

You can [visit here](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_td_colspan.asp) to see the colspan property

```
<table>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <asp:Label Text="Team :" runat="server"></asp:Label>
            </td>
            <td colspan="2">
                <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlProject" OnSelectedIndexChanged="itemSelected" 
                    AutoPostBack="True" runat="server"></asp:DropDownList>
             </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <asp:Label Text="Project :" runat="server"></asp:Label>
            </td>
            <td colspan="2">
                <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlDetails" runat="server">
                </asp:DropDownList>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <asp:Button ID="btnBugSubmit" Text="Bug" 
                  OnClick="btnBugSubmit_Click" runat="server"/>
            </td>
            <td>
                <asp:Button ID="btnIssueSubmit" Text="Issue" 
                OnClick="btnIssueSubmit_Click" runat="server"/>
            </td>
            <td >
                <asp:Button ID="btnReqSubmit" Text="Requisition" 
                 OnClick="btnReqSubmit_Click" runat="server"/>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

Answer (score 0):

This issue is happening because of the second line `project` dropdown's width is more

If you are using table structure this issue will come

Because the column's width will be adjusted to the maximum width of the cell in the column

Use `div` and `span` instead

see the below demo

```css
input[type="button"] {
    margin:5px;
    width:50px;
}

label {
    border:none
    width:10px;
}
select {
    width:100px;
}
```

```html
<div>
        <div>
            <span>
                <label>Text</label></span>
            <span>
                <select></select></span>
        </div>
        <div>
            <span>
                <label>Text</label></span>
            <span>
                <select></select></span>
        </div>
        <div>
            <span>
                <input type="button"/></span>
            <span>
                <input type="button"/></span>
            <span>
                <input type="button"/></span>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your have created 2 cells for first two row and 3 for last row, so

Replace last `tr` with below code

```
<tr>
            <td>
                <asp:Button ID="btnBugSubmit" Text="Bug" OnClick="btnBugSubmit_Click" runat="server"/></td>
            <td>
                <asp:Button ID="btnIssueSubmit" Text="Issue" OnClick="btnIssueSubmit_Click" runat="server"/>

                <asp:Button ID="btnReqSubmit" Text="Requisition" OnClick="btnReqSubmit_Click" runat="server"/></td>
        </tr>
```